# Installed IE Toolbar not visible in IE

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc

I have developed a IE toolbar which is working fine in my system ,But in some of the other system when i register it through command "**regsvr32 /s /c DLL-PATH**" ,It makes a entry in registry and i can see that in Manage-Addons screen where it shows enable but it is not visible in IE.I am not getting any prompt to enable Add-on from IE either.But if i download and install Last-Pass Toolbar ,My toolbar also get start showing in IE.Is there any settings to make IE prompt for enabling Add-on which is not coming in my toolbar case.

Answer (score 0):

An IE add-on requires additional registry keys to the normal COM component keys. This article describes them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer,This has been done by me,Otherwise it won't have run in my system either.

Comment: Have you checked that the required registry keys are also set in the other computers?